# How to pass the entire request url from vhost configuration file in apache xampp

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to get the request URL from the vhost configuration file in XAMPP.
(file path is xampp\apache\conf\extra\vhost.conf)
i have used

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} accountno=(.*)&username=(.*)&password=(.*)
```

It is parsed successfully and i need to put this QUERY_STRING into a variable.
I'm unable to do it could anyone please help me out.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here. The query string already _is_ available in a variable - `%{QUERY_STRING}`, which you are using already to access its content to match it against your regular expression. What else do you need now?

Comment: And what you mean by _“get the request URL from the vhost configuration file in XAMPP”_, is also not clear. You tagged this `htaccess` - so _where_ are you actually configuring this now, in the .htaccess inside a project folder, or in the vhost configuration? Or what do you mean by _“from the vhost configuration”_?

Answer (score 0):

Just using RewriteCond{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
And accessing using %1